# Using facet.exists=true with faceting on specific terms in solr

Tags: solr, facet

As per the documentation provided here: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_2/faceting.html#limiting-facet-with-certain-terms we can facet on specific terms in a field by using

`http://localhost:8984/solr/sprod/select?fq=codes%3A%20%5B*%20TO%20*%5D&q=*%3A*&rows=0&facet=true&facet.field={!terms=0gKAosFmC6YBF,561hWSf7Cxc4J}codes`

this returns the output as:

```
"facet_counts":{
    "facet_queries":{},
    "facet_fields":{
      "codes":[
        "0gKAosFmC6YBF",46570,
        "561hWSf7Cxc4J",46466]},
    "facet_ranges":{},
    "facet_intervals":{},
    "facet_heatmaps":{}}}
```

However, I would want to just get if the given term exists or not and don't care about their count.

Using the following:
`http://localhost:8984/solr/sprod/select?fq=codes%3A%20%5B*%20TO%20*%5D&q=*%3A*&rows=0&facet=true&facet.field={!terms=0gKAosFmC6YBF,561hWSf7Cxc4J}codes&facet.exists=true`

still returns the counts for the terms, is there a different syntax that needs to be followed when using the `Limiting Facet with Certain Terms` synatx?

Comment: What's the reason for why you can't have the actual count present?

Comment: @MatsLindh I am fine with having the actual count, but was hoping that just asking for existence, if possible, may give some perf boost for avg case (although may not for the worst case)

Comment: As long as you have `docValues` enabled for the field, I'm guessing it will mostly be the same. But sure, there would be a slight difference; using the terms component instead might be an option if you run into problems.